# Mono 3.2.1 Embeded image in mail is not displayed

Tags: c#, mono, jpeg

I have a C# Visual studio 2010 application for sending the mails.

There is JPGE image embedded in the mail by using Linkedresource. 
The application is working fine with Visual studio 2010 and showing embedded image in the mail.

The same application while working with mono 3.2.1 on ubuntu 13.10 is not working properly. 
With mono, it is showing the embedded image in the mail but it is blank image.

I checked on the internet and found one bug reported for the same issue for mono version 2.10.8.1 ,Bug No is 17207. 
I wish to know is this bug fixed or is there any workaround for this problem.

Comment: mono 2.10.8.1 is no longer a supported version of mono, please upgrade

Comment: Tested in Mono 3.2.1 but still not displaying image in the mail.

Comment: cool, then update your question